# db2 sql, how to get min and max value only in the same query with one table?

Tags: sql, db2, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

with this query

```
SELECT distinct name,MIN(price) minprice, MAX(price) maxprice FROM cars where group='CNO' GROUP BY name HAVING MIN(price) > 1 order by minprice;
```

i obtain this result

```
NAME                                     MINPRICE    MAXPRICE   
---------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
Super CNO                                      20000       20000
CNO 340                                        40000       40000
CNO 110                                        60000       60000
CNO 790                                       100000      100000
```

How to get only the MIN and MAX price to see what car is most expensive?
Something like this

```
NAME                                     MINPRICE    MAXPRICE   
---------------------------------------- ----------- -----------
Super CNO                                      20000       20000
CNO 790                                       100000      100000
```

of course we don't know the min and max price before the query so between 20000 and 100000 is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions. Your results show min and max with the same value, which makes me suspect that is only one row per name. If so:

```
select *
from (
    select name, price,
        rank() over(order by price desc) rn_desc,
        rank() over(order by price) rn_asc
    from cars 
    where price > 1
) c
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```

If you really need aggregation:

```
select *
from (
    select name, min(price) min_price, max(price) max_price
        rank() over(order by max(price) desc) rn_desc,
        rank() over(order by min(price)) rn_asc
    from cars 
    group by name
    having min(price) > 1
) c
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
```